# ¿Cómo validar que el contenido de una cadena de texto es un número mayor a 0?

Tags: java, string

No sé como hacer lo siguiente:

Necesito validar estos 3 datos:

```
String Equiv1="";
String Equiv2="";
String equivalencia1;
```

La duda la tengo con `equivalencia1` es que debe ser un número mayor a 0. Tengo este código:

```
public int probarEquiv1 (){
    Equiv1 =ConversorNou.PrimeraDivisaTXT.getText();
    Equiv2 = ConversorNou.SegundaDivisaTXT.getText();
    equivalencia1 = ConversorNou.EquivalenciaTXT.getCharCount();
    if(Equiv1.equalsIgnoreCase("Euro")&& Equiv2.equalsIgnoreCase("Dolar")&& ......... ){
        return 1;

    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
```

Por ahora he validado que `Equiv1` represente `"Euro"`, `Equiv2` represente `"Dolar"`, pero ¿cómo puedo hacer que también verifique que `equivalencia1` sea mayor a 0?

¿Hay alguna forma más limpia de hacerlo?

Es decir, mi idea era hacer un `if-else` para hacer más condiciones extras. Por ejemplo que `Equiv1` a parte de `"Euro"` también sea correcto si pongo `"Dolar"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Una opción limpia es intentar convertir la cadena a un número. Asumo que este número puede aceptar decimales, por lo cual no sería correcto utilizar `Integer` ni `Long` ni similares para la conversión. Asimismo, puesto que vas a realizar operaciones sobre este número, te convendría aprovechar su valor al convertirlo. La mejor opción para este caso es convertir el número a [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html):

```
try {
    //crear la instancia de BigDecimal
    BigDecimal monto = new BigDecimal(equivalencia1);
    //si la instancia pudo ser creada, el texto es un número válido
    //caso contrario, se lanza la excepción NumberFormatException
    //validar que el número es mayor a 0.
    if (monto.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) <= 0) {
        //resto de tu código para calcular la equivalencia
        //...
    } else {
        //el número ingresado es menor o igual a 0
    }
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    //mostrar un mensaje de error al usuario indicando que
    //no ha ingresado un número correcto
}
```

Comment: Es lo que explico no es esto 100% lo que necesito.

Tengo que verificar varias cosas.
Equiv1 sea o euro o dolar
Equiv2 sea o euro o dolar pero no se repita con Equiv1

Equivalencia1 sea un valor númerico positivo ( mayor de 0 ) y puede admitir decimales.

Comment: @MontseMkd puedes utilizar este código para agregar a tu parte de validación. El código presentado en las respuestas no es solo para que lo copies, pegues y funcione mágicamente. Con esto quiero decir que si adaptas el código presentado aquí como parte de tu validación, esto es, incluyendo tus validaciones actuales, es muy posible que funcione. Además, tu pregunta se enfoca en cómo realzar una validación en particular, no en cómo tener todas las validaciones funcionando correctamente.

Comment: @MontseMkd creo que sería un mejor diseño en tu aplicación tanto para el usuario como para tus validaciones si en lugar de que el usuario ingrese la divisa como cadena de texto pueda seleccionar el valor de una lista desplegable así solo validas el valor de los elementos seleccionados y te ahorras muchos problemas de validación y mantenimiento.

Comment: el problema es que es un ejercicio y tengo que hacerlo así que es como está propuesto no puedo modificarlo a mi antojo.

De la forma que yo lo he hecho no la más correcta pero me da la funcionalidad que necesito.

Comment: Si supiera hacerlo no pediría ayuda.. he intentado resolverlo pero sé que no es correcto 100% si podéis aporartme algo mejor a mi código genial.

Comment: @MontseMkd entiendo. Por favor ten en cuenta que nosotros los lectores no tenemos una bola mágica de cristal para saber lo que sucede en sus ambientes particulares ni contexto. Aclarar todos esos detalles al momento de redactar la pregunta facilita la comprensión no solo del problema sino también del contexto.

Comment: @MontseMkd este código aporta puesto que sirve para validar si el texto: 1) es un número, 2) es un número mayor a 0. El hecho de que lo puedas o no comprender, ya no depende de mí.

Comment: Si pero el problema que veo es que al ser Integer evaluara mal si pongo un decimal me equivoco? 

Si pregunto es por que no lo entiendo...

Comment: Me explico mejor, de la forma que yo lo he hecho al pasarlo a integer lo hago mal ya que los decimales me los dará por erroneos. Por eso tu haces lo del bigDecimal no?

Comment: En esta solución es todo lo contrario: acepta tanto valores enteros como decimales. Recuerda que los números enteros son en realidad un subconjunto de los valores reales, y `BigDecimal` soporta todo tipo de números. Inclusive, `BigDecimal` ya está preparado para trabajar con grandes cantidades de enteros y decimales, (en teoría) no está afecto a overflows.

Comment: PErfecto ahora ya lo entiendo! es que no sabía que era el BigDecimal. 

Mil gracias Luiggi lo pruebo! ;)

Comment: Para eso está el enlace en el texto. Los enlaces son para proveer información adicional, te recomiendo que los revises si tienes tiempo para profundizar en los conocimientos, no solo en mis respuestas sino en respuestas de cualquier persona en la comunidad.

Comment: Perdona acabo de descubrirlo no sabía que eran enlaces! Gracias!

Comment: Para ayudarte :)

Answer (score 2):

Es correcta la validación como la comentas para un valor entero que sea mayor a 0, simplemente agrega en tu validación que verifique:

equivalencia1 > 0

quedaría:

```
if(Equiv1.equalsIgnoreCase("Euro")&& Equiv2.equalsIgnoreCase("Dolar")&& equivalencia1 > 0 ){
    return 1;
}
else{
    return 0;
}
```

Seria más rápido para tu código agregarlo en la misma validación que tener 3 validaciones.

incluso puedes cambiar tu método para que obtengas un valor boleano verdadero, si se cumplen las 3 condiciones:

```
public boolean probarEquiv1 (){
    Equiv1 =ConversorNou.PrimeraDivisaTXT.getText();
    Equiv2 = ConversorNou.SegundaDivisaTXT.getText();
    equivalencia1 = ConversorNou.EquivalenciaTXT.getCharCount();
    if(Equiv1.equalsIgnoreCase("Euro")&& Equiv2.equalsIgnoreCase("Dolar")&& equivalencia1 > 0){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
```

ok debiste especificar que equivalencia1 se tendría que evaluar anteriormente ya que proviene originalmente de un valor String:

usando este método:

```
 private static int obtieneValorNumerico(String cadena){
            try {
               return  Integer.parseInt(cadena); //convierte el string a int.
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe){
                return 0; // no es numerico define 0 por default.
            }
}
```

se puede evaluar de esta forma:

```
    if ( Equiv1.equalsIgnoreCase("Dolar")&& Equiv2.equalsIgnoreCase("Euro")&& obtieneValorNumerico(equivalencia1)>0){
        return 1;               
        }else{
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: es lo que había hecho pero me da error... :S no entiendo el motivo.. 

Le hago el return 1 por que lo enlazo a otra parte del programa ! ;)

Comment: Pongo en Equivalencia1 -1 y me da true.. 
Pongo en Equivalencia1 la letra k y me da true..

Comment: Es decir lo que hace el Equivalencia > 0 es que siempre que ponga un dato en ese cuadro saldra True... 

Necesito que me verifique que es NUMERO y que es positivo.

Comment: No creo que todos los montos sean valores enteros solamente.

Comment: que significa montos? :S

Comment: El valor Equivalencia es String hay que pasarlo a int y comprobar que es positivo, y puede contener decimales... por eso no se hacerlo.. T_T

Comment: @MontseMkd monto = valor de dinero, cash, efectivo, plata, etc.

Comment: @Elenasys si por ejemplo en vez de Int lo pongo a double entonces podría introducir decimales no?

Comment: Montse asi es, si lo conviertes a double puedes introducir decimales.

Answer (score -2):

Resuelto!

No se si es la mejor forma..

```
import javax.print.attribute.standard.Copies;

public class DatosUser {
public DatosUser(){

}
    String Equiv1="";
    String Equiv2="";
    String equivalencia1="";

    public int probarEquiv1 (){
    Equiv1 =ConversorNou.PrimeraDivisaTXT.getText();
    Equiv2 = ConversorNou.SegundaDivisaTXT.getText();
    equivalencia1 = ConversorNou.EquivalenciaTXT.getText();
    if(Equiv1.equalsIgnoreCase("Euro")&& Equiv2.equalsIgnoreCase("Dolar")&& DatosUser.esDecimal1(equivalencia1)){
        return 1;
    }
    else if ( Equiv1.equalsIgnoreCase("Dolar")&& Equiv2.equalsIgnoreCase("Euro")&& DatosUser.isNumeric(equivalencia1)){
    return 1;               
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }

}

     private static boolean isNumeric(String cadena){
            try {
                Integer.parseInt(cadena);
                return true;
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe){
                return false;
            }}


     public static boolean esDecimal1(String cad)
     {
     boolean hayPunto=false;
     StringBuffer parteEntera = new StringBuffer();
     StringBuffer parteDecimal = new StringBuffer();
     int i=0, posicionDelPunto;

     for( i=0;i<cad.length(); i++ )
     if ( cad.charAt(i) == '.')                          //Detectar si hay un punto decimal en la cadena
     hayPunto=true;
     if(hayPunto)                                            //Si hay punto guardar la posicion donde se encuentra el carater punto
     posicionDelPunto=cad.indexOf('.');                  //(si la cadena tiene varios puntos, detecta donde esta el primero).
     else
     return false;                                       //Si no hay punto; no es decimal

     if( posicionDelPunto == cad.length()-1 || posicionDelPunto== 0)    //Si el punto esta al final o al principio no es un decimal
     return false;

     for( i=0;i<posicionDelPunto; i++ )
     parteEntera.append(cad.charAt(i)) ;                 //Guardar la parte entera en una variable

     for(i = 0; i<parteEntera.length(); i++)
     if( ! Character.isDigit(parteEntera.charAt(i)) )    //Si alguno de los caracteres de la parte entera no son digitos no es decimal
     return false;

     for( i=posicionDelPunto+1;i<cad.length(); i++ )
     parteDecimal.append(cad.charAt(i));                 //Guardar la parte decimal en una variable

     for(i = 0; i<parteDecimal.length(); i++)
     if( ! Character.isDigit(parteDecimal.charAt(i)) )   //Si alguno de los caracteres de la parte decimal no es un digito no es decimal
     return false;                                   //Incluye el caso en el que la cadena tenga dos o mas puntos

     return true;                                            //Si paso todas las pruebas anteriores, la cadena es un Numero decimal
     }


     public boolean esDecimal(String cad)
     {
     try
     {
       Double.parseDouble(cad);
       return true;
     }
     catch(NumberFormatException nfe)
     {
       return false;
     }




    }
}
```

Comment: Esta respuesta no tiene ningún sentido. En la pregunta indicas que `equivalencia1` es de tipo `int` y ahora en esta respuesta mágicamente ha cambiado su tipo a `String`. Por favor edita tu pregunta para reflejar **tu problema real** y poder resolverlo. Ten en cuenta que tus preguntas y respuestas deben ayudar no solo a ti sino a futuros lectores en la comunidad.

Comment: @Elenasys el problema está en el tipo de dato. Al parecer la pregunta es cómo comprobar que una cadena de texto es un número mayor a 0.

Comment: no creo necesario el if else if else con evaluar todo una vez puedes retornar 1 o 0 revisa mi respuesta Montse.. :)

Comment: Os comento, tengo que evaluar 3 cosas.

Comment: 1. Equiv1 ( es un string que sea Euro o Dolar )
2. Equiv2 ( es un string que sea Euro o Dolar pero que no se repita con Equiv1 )
3. Equivalencia1 es un int ( es decir el usuario introducirá si o si un numero que tiene que ser mayor que 0 y con decimales.

podéis ayudarme?

Comment: mi solución es chapucera pero me da lo que necesito

Comment: @MontseMkd tienes que evaluar 3 cosas pero necesitas ayuda con 1 sola, las demás ya están hechas. Nota: no siempre puedes validar todo en 1 solo `if`.